# Phonegap doesn't show images

Tags: image, cordova

I have a problem with my current application built with PhoneGap. Images are not loading :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p5bv.png

Here is my code:

```
<div id="center_content">
    <div id="dashboard">
        <a href="#scheduler" onclick="loadxml();">
        <img src="images/horario.png" class="dashboard_icon"/></a>
    <a href="#tests" onclick="loadjson();">
    <img src="images/examenes.png" class="dashboard_icon"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/tareas.png" class="dashboard_icon"/</a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/tareas.png" class="dashboard_icon"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/herramientas.png" class="dashboard_icon"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/configuracion.png" class="dashboard_icon"/></a>
    <img src="images/tareas.png" class="dashboard_icon"/>
    <img src="images/tareas.png" class="dashboard_icon"/>
    <img src="examenes.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2: and here the application structure:

PG\assets\www (contains the html page) and the image folder...PG\assets\www\images\

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Looks like your images aren't loading. How about some code?

Comment: Could you give use the structure of your app folder.

Comment: Honestly, there should be no reason why those images don't load. What platform are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have specified the correct directory for the images. Try putting the actual http link to the images as the src. For example, "http://yourdomain.com/images/tareas.png"

Comment: Worked, mayby PhoneGap doesn't load images locally. So annoying. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. PhoneGap can be weird sometimes.